# is there an OpenCL std::queue equivalent

Tags: c++, opencl

I have some code that is in a similar form to this:

```
std::queue<unsigned> q; 
q.push(array[0]); 

while (!q.empty()) 
{ 
    unsigned index = q.front(); 
    q.pop(); 

    if(index >= someval){ 
        index = index - someval;  
        q.push(array[index]); 
    } 
    else{ 
        //do something
    } 
} 
}
```

I would like to move this over to an OpenCL kernel, how would I replicate the functionality of the queue in the most efficient way possible.

At the moment I have implemented it with a fixed sized array which monitors the head and count of elements in the queue. I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks

Comment: Is this about host side queue mechanism or some sort of stack in kernel code?

Comment: It would be a stack in kernel code

Comment: All local and global variables must be known length at compile time. But threads can share areas of it. Are you asking this? Such as 1MB global shared by 256 threads, one consuming 10 bytes while another 80kB, .. this is possible using atomic add function and some synchronizations

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you mean but this would need to be individual to all threads on the GPU, I can estimate that the queue will not grow past 64 elements so knowing the length at compile time is not a problem.

Comment: The code above would be what makes up the kernel code.

Comment: but pop is not applicable on global scope. Only local scope in only single workgroup such as 256 threads. Because a single thread may pop between two push of another two threads. Without existence of global barrier (which doesn't exist), you cannot use more than one local workgroup to pop a queue. Maybe you can convert a queue to N queues then later concatenate them in host side or at one of kernels.

Comment: And if it is for single thread, you should check c++ version of opencl which is called sycl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check SYCL: https://www.khronos.org/sycl where  where C++ template functions can contain both host and device code to construct complex algorithms that use OpenCL acceleration. If you can't use that and if you don't even have a device for opencl 2.0:

There isn't any equivalent for version 1.2. But in comments, you said:

> Not sure that I understand what you mean but this would need to be individual to all threads on the GPU

Then there is no need for inter-thread communication, it should be simple to implement a FIFO one using a circular buffer for cache+memory+compute efficiency, just don't overflow it(64 elements max) and don't underflow(more pops than pushes but easy to implement a bounds check (with performance penalty)):

push

```
   bool push(__private uint * stack, uint value)
    {
        // pushing from bot, so you can pop it from top later (FIFO)
        // circular buffer for top performance
        uint bufLen=64;
        // zeroth element is counter for newest added element
        // first element is oldest element


        // circular buffer 
        uint nextIndex=(stack[0]%bufLen+2); // +2 because of top-bot headers

        // if overflows, it overwrites oldest elements one by one
        stack[nextIndex]=value;


        // if overflows, it still increments 
        stack[0]++;

        // simple and fast
        return true;
    }
```

checking if empty

```
        bool empty(__private uint * stack)
        {
            // tricky if you overflow both
            return (stack[0]==stack[1]);
        }
```

front value

```
        uint front(__private uint * stack)
        {
            uint bufLen=64;

            // oldest element value (top)
            uint ptr=stack[1]%bufLen+2; // circular adr + 2 header


            return stack[ptr];
        }
```

popping

```
        uint pop(__private uint * stack)
        {
               uint bufLen=64;
               uint ptr=stack[1]%bufLen+2;
               // pop from top (oldest)
               uint returnValue=stack[ptr];
               stack[ptr]=0;

               // this will be new top ctr for ptr
               stack[1]++;

               // if underflows, gets garbage, don't underflow

               return returnValue;
        }
```

example kernel for benchmarking:

```
        __kernel void queue0(__global uint * heap)
        {
            int id=get_global_id(0);
            __private uint q[100];
            for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
                q[i]=0;

            for(int i=0;i<55;i++)    
                push(q,i);

            for(int i=0;i<40;i++)    
                pop(q);

            for(int i=0;i<20;i++)    
                push(q,i);

            for(int i=0;i<35;i++)    
                pop(q);

            for(int i=0;i<35;i++)    
            {
                push(q,i);
                pop(q);
            }
            push(q,'h');
            push(q,'e');
            push(q,'l');
            push(q,'l');
            push(q,'o');
            push(q,' ');
            push(q,'w');
            push(q,'o');
            push(q,'r');
            push(q,'l');
            push(q,'d');
            for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
                heap[id*256+i]=q[i];
        }
```

output of buffer (which shows thread id = 0 calculations results)

```
121 110 0      0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0 // 121 pushes total, 110 pops total

0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0

0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0

0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0

104 101 108      108 111 32     119 111 114    108 100 0 
// hello world
```

more than 200k pushes+pops under 6.35 milliseconds(running kernel for 1024 threads each working on 256 elements but using only 64+2 elements for circular buffer) for a 1-channel 1600MHz ddr3 RAM and Intel HD Graphics 400 with 12 compute units(96 cores total @600 MHz).

If you construct a 64-element circular buffer using 64 x 4-element circular buffers, you can add elements between top and bottom of stack too!